# how to place Imageview and textview horizontally, in card view,I used android:orientation="horizontal"> in linear lyt but get vertical alignment

Tags: android

I have 2 doubts-
1>how to place Imageview and textview horizontally, I used android:orientation="horizontal"> but get vertical alignment
2> spinner control is showing only 1 value, though I entered 5 values; others are not selected

In main activity, I am embedding a spinner and an edit text inside a card view. In the card view, I am embedding a flag image in image view and a textview that shows country code ISD.

I want this->[image: want this]
but getting this->[image]

CODE:

```
MainActivity:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{


    String[] countryNames={"+91","+86","+61","+351","+1","+64"};
    int flags[] = {R.drawable.india, R.drawable.china, R.drawable.australia, R.drawable.portugal, R.drawable.america, R.drawable.new_zealand};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Getting the instance of Spinner and applying OnItemSelectedListener on it
        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),flags,countryNames);
        spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }


    //Performing action onItemSelected and onNothing selected
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), countryNames[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
```

CustomAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int flags[];
    String[] countryNames;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] flags, String[] countryNames) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.flags = flags;
        this.countryNames = countryNames;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return flags.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items, null);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        icon.setImageResource(flags[i]);
        names.setText(countryNames[i]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/simpleSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Hello World!"
              />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

custom_spinner_items.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" /><!--Make sure image is present in Drawable folder-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Enter phone number"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should use a `ConstraintLayout`, it's more efficient than having multiple hierarchies inside `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because you have placed the cardView inside the LinearLayout and not the contents of the CardView . You need to create a LinearLayout inside the CardView and then assign it horizontal to the orientation property to achieve your needs .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/simpleSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Hello World!"
              />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
```